# creating a filled in rectangle/shape around text using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a pre-existing image that I have added a border to and text, I would like to place a rectangle around the text area to make it similar to a gold embedded plate on a picture or painting.
I am using draw.text to write and position the text, but can't figure out how to do the shape border & fill around the text parameters.

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import glob


## SINGLE IMAGE

img = Image.open('Art/AB-2020 (2).jpg')
add_grey_border = ImageOps.expand(img,border=50,fill='grey')
add_black_border = ImageOps.expand(add_grey_border,border=300,fill='black')
add_black_border.save('Art/imaged-with-border.png')

## Function to add Title to image

def add_title(img_src, title):

    img = Image.open(img_src, 'r')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    w, h = img.size
    
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 100)
    text_w, text_h = draw.textsize(title, font)

    draw.text(((w - text_w) / 2, (h-100) - text_h), title, (255,255,255), 
    font=font, stroke_width=2, stroke_fill='#eeda19')
    img.save(img_src)
    return img_src

add_title('Art/imaged-with-border.png', 'test')
```

what I have so far:
[painting with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MiG8.jpg)

If I can get the nameplate correct I will remove the stroke_fill.

I want it to look like this:
[What I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b7sV.jpg)

Comment: Please show your complete code, with `import` statements and input and expected output image. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell updated, thank you